# symfony validation doesn't work

Tags: symfony, validation, entity, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

I guess there is something I'm missing.
I have a User entity which is validated through a `yml` file but every time I send a post request to the route it seems it doesn't get my request. With this I mean that the route works fine but I keep getting the error messages that the password and username *should not be blank* (due to the constraints i set). So it seems it's not getting my request validated against the entity.

I made sure to have this settings triggered in my config:
`validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }`

Here is  my `routing.yml`:

```
user_login_homepage:
    path:     /check
    defaults: { _controller: UserLoginBundle:Login:checkCredentials }
    methods: [POST]
```

Here is my `validation.yml`

```
User\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: ~
        password:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

Here is my controller (`LoginController.php`)

```
public function checkCredentialsAction(Request $request)
{
    $recursiveValidator = $this->get('validator');

    $user = new User();

    $errors = $recursiveValidator->validate($user);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        $errorsString = (string) $errors;
        return new Response($errorsString);
    }

    return new Response('Yuppy');
}
```

I've just tried to follow the instructions but I'm not able to have it work :(
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating an empty User so It's correct the error, try this (I have imagine that username and password are passed into POST data right?):

```
$user = new User();
$postData = $request->request->all();
$user->setUsername($postData['username'];
$user->setPassword($postData['password'];

$errors = $recursiveValidator->validate($user);
```

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot. Yes they are being passed by POST. Just a question related to your solution. Doesn't is save those data in the table in that way?

Comment: In this way you fill the entity, check errors and after you can save It or wat you want, if you are using symfony form you can automatically fill the user with form passed by the form

Comment: Yeah I know that but the difference in this case lies in the fact that I'm not using the form so it was a bit different!
Cheers man! :)